# Rails joined queries with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables -

User - expires

Interest - user_id,content

I want to get all Users who have an expiry greater than now and whose interests contain a specified term.

I've tried

```
Interest.where('content LIKE ?','%#{search_term}%')
```

and then getting the Users from that but I'm looking for a single query way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
User.joins(:interests).where('interests.content LIKE ? and users.expires > ?', "%#{search_term}", Time.now)
```

Comment: Thanks for that Marek. After some work with the console, I just got this working.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I'm assuming that a user has_many :interests.

```
User.joins(:interests).where('interests.content LIKE ?', "%#{search_term}%")
  .where('expires > ?', Time.now)
```

You might also want to look at the squeel gem, as it has some nicer ways to express conditions like this that look more ruby-ish.

Comment: I was just about to post a solution for this but you beat me to it! Thanks sockmonk! And the squeel gem looks great. Will check it out.